# Disabling print and selection in Flexpaper HTML5

Tags: html, flexpaper

I want to know how to disable  print and selection in Adaptive UI of Flexpaper, specially HTML5 version. I have different types of users in my website, some of them can print and select text in the PDF, others can only print, and another group can just read (not print, not selection). How can i do this in Adaptive UI in HTML5 version?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this link: http://flexpaper.devaldi.com/docs_parameters.jsp. It has got all solutions to your problem. You can configure the viewer to show or hide certain tools by passing appropriate values in jquery while initializing the viewer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that disabling print option is available in the licensed readonly versions of the product